# jQuery plugin - issue using HTML5 data attributes as alternate config options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to make my first jQuery plugin and I have hit a bit of a problem trying to extend the plugin to accept HTML5 data attributes. A user should be able to initiate and tweak settings by just using data attributes in the HTML (a user could also still init in script if so desired).

Some example HTML:

```
<ul id="list" data-foo-scroll="true" data-foo-fadeIn="1">
 <li>Phone 1</li>
</ul>
```

The data-foo-scroll auto inits the plugin fine but im now trying (and failing) to pass in the fadeIn attribute.

Here is my plugin js:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = "fooScroll",
        defaults = {
            loadingText:    "loading",
            loadingClass:   "foo-loading",
            showText:       "show more",
            nextLink:       ".next",
            fadeIn:         500,
            autoLoad:       false,
            autoLoadOffset: 100
        };

    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this._next = $(this._defaults.nextLink).attr('href');
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {
            $(this.options.nextLink).hide();    
            this.getNextPage(this.element, this.options);
        },

        getNextPage: function(el, options) {
            var self = this;
            if(this.options.autoLoad===true) {
                this.options.showText = '&nbsp';
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                       $('#foo-more').trigger('click');
                   }
                });
            };
            $(el).after("<div id='foo-more'><a href='#'>"+this.options.showText+"</a></div>")
            $("#foo-more").on("click", function(event){
                $('#foo-more a').text(options.loadingText);
                $('#foo-more').addClass(options.loadingClass);
                $.ajax({
                    url: self._next,
                    datatype: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var list;
                        $(el).attr('id') ? list = '#'+$(el).attr('id'): list = '.'+$(el).attr('class');
                        $(el).append('<div class="foo-new" />');
                        $(el).find('div:last').append( $('<div />').html(data).find(list).children()).hide();

                        // if ajax returns any images then delay DOM update until they are all loaded
                        if ($('<div />').html(data).find(list).find('img').length > 0) {
                            $(el).find('img').on('load', function() { 
                                self.showNextPage();
                            });
                        } else {
                            self.showNextPage();
                        }
                        // update show me more link with latest href
                        self._next = $('<div />').html(data).find(options.nextLink).attr('href');
                        // if ajax doesnt return a next button then hide show me more link
                        if (($('<div />').html(data).find(options.nextLink).length == 0)) $('#foo-more').remove();
                    }
                })
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        },

        showNextPage: function() {
            $(this.element).find('div.foo-new:last').fadeIn(this.options.fadeIn); 
            $('#foo-more a').text(this.options.showText);
            $('#foo-more').removeClass(this.options.loadingClass);
        }     

    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var objD = $(this).data();
            console.log(objD);
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

    // auto init
    $("[data-foo-scroll='true']").fooScroll();


})( jQuery, window, document );
```

note the console.log does print out:

```
Object { fooFadein=1, fooScroll=true }
```

So its being picked up but I cant work out how to actually 'use' it as part of the plugin.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

THis docs explain it pretty clearly, have a read through them.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

What I see you are trying to do is: `var fooFadein = $(this).attr('foo-fadeIn')`

Comment: how does tat fit in with the plugin though? I can get the data-attributes picked up looking at the logs but cant work out how to init them

Comment: I dont't undestant what you mean by "init them"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, wouldn't you just have to merge the custom attribute values into the option parameter to the plugin?

```
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
  return this.each(function () {
    if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
      var objD = $(this).data();
      $.extend(options, objD); // extend with data-stuff
      $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Simon, exactly. I tried the above, but the default options value for FadeIn seems to override that found in the data-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out how to get it working (see below) Plugin could be something like this (extending jquery plugin boilerplate):

```
function Plugin( element, options, objD ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options, objD );
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}

$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
  return this.each(function () {
    if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        var objD = $(this).data();
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options, objD ));
    }
  });
};
```

Im no guru but works well for me

Comment: Well that's strange, just one question: are your data-attribute examples the same way you set them in your html? Because if you define data-foo-fadeIn, the actual key in the .data() collection would be "foo-fadeIn" instead of "fadeIn", which ofcourse wouldn't merge into the options correctly.

Comment: @Simon Yea and if we forget the 'foo', if you have `o.fadeIn` your data-attribute has to be `data-fade-in=""` and _not_ `data-fadeIn=""`. Although, if you had `o.fadein`, your data-attribute could be `data-fadeIn=""` or if you wanted, it could be `data-FaDeIn=""`. Here's a very stripped down example of that first example http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/cL7ve/

Comment: Oh well, didn't know jQuery builds it with camelCase anyway, thanks for the input @Joonas